# Broadcast receiver that listens to hard button in android

Tags: android, button, broadcastreceiver

Is there a cross device hard button in android that a background service can listen to and act when it is pressed/released?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can set up a `BroadcastReceiver` to watch for the CAMERA or MEDIA buttons, but those are not always available -- some devices do not have the CAMERA button, and the MEDIA button is for use with wired headsets.

Sorry!

Comment: agreed.  not all devices are created equal.